# Generation of UML class diagram for grails project

Tags: grails

I included `graphviz.dot.executable = "C:/Program Files/release/bin/dot.exe"` in config.groovy and installed class diagram plugin using plugin manager in grails GGTS 2.2.1

After installation, a class diagram of my domain classes was not available under `http://localhost:8080/myApp/classDiagram` instead of that preference page is shown

can anyone suggest me a solution for this

Comment: Which version of Grails? If it's Grails 2, you should be aware there's a [big red box on the plugin page](http://grails.org/plugin/class-diagram/) which says `This plugin does not work with grails 2.0 yet!`

Comment: @tim ya my grails version is 2.2.1, then how to install class diagram plugin and how to get my project class diagram can you suggest me a link for class diagram plugin for grails 2.2.1 version

Comment: 1) You can't 2) I don't know 3) I don't think there is one 4) Maybe you should team up with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588813/414-request-uri-too-large-for-uml-class-diagram-in-grails